# LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation

Tags: maven, glassfish, spring-boot

I try to start my spring boot in tomcat server but when I'm adding some external jars to my project :

```
appsert-rt.jar
gf-client.jar
javaee.jar
```

it gives me that error :

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory loaded from file:/C:/Users/amar/Documents/glassfish-3.1/glassfish/modules/bean-validator.jar). If you are using Weblogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:339)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLoggerContext(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.getLogger(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:143)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.beforeInitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:89)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:132)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:122)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.started(EventPublishingRunListener.java:54)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:278)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:961)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:950)
        at demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:14)
```

My pom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <projectxmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.udev</groupId>
    <artifactId>udev</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.DemoApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

  </project>
```

note : it work perfectly when i remove the jars / One problem could be conflits between classes of slf4j in my maven added jars and those added externelly

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm confused. Your question says you're running your app in a Tomcat server but the stacktrace suggests you're running it via the main method. Furthermore, the exception message suggests you're using Glassfish 3.1, or at least some of its jars. Can you clarify exactly how you're running the app and how you have configured its classpath?

Comment: Okey, so I have an EJB deployed in a glassfish 3.1 and i want to use it from a standalone we client sprint boot, i must include mainly the gf-client to the client class path te be able to initialise the context and perform a lookup

Comment: @reza how to avoid this error

Answer (score 0):

There is a conflict between the jars declared in your maven project and those you imported explicitly.

Dependency analysis is one of the great benefits of using a tool like Maven, but it cannot do anything about dependencies that you are manually adding a runtime.
What you should do is add those jars as dependencies to your maven project.  Once you do that you can use the Maven Dependency Plugin to find the conflicting packages, and add exclusions for packages that conflict.